# Double integrated printing

Tags: virtual-machine, printing, hyper-v, windows-xp-mode

I have a Windows XP Mode VM, inside of a Windows 7 VM guest using Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Host. How do I print from the Windows XP all the way through to the Windows 10 printer? As a temporary solution, I am sharing network folders between the 3 OS, and that is ok, but I would like to print from the XP VM. Of course, the modern printer I am using will not have Windows XP drivers available, so I am seeking for a solution without using normal drivers. What is a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Same as single VM, so long as the XP VM can see the local network, & therefore the printer on it, it can print to it. [Though this makes me suspect your printer is connected over USB, or you'd have probably discovered that by now.]

Comment: Any windows machine can share a printer hooked up through USB.  You don't need a "print server". Then use the local network as mentioned by other people here.

Answer (score 2):

Put your printer on a Print Server or connect it to your network directly with Ethernet. An extra device (print server) is only need if there is not an Ethernet port. Most printers today (not all) have an Ethernet connection, obviating the need for a print server.

Once connected, install the driver on the virtual machines as well as the host and it will print just fine.

I do this myself.

Comment: John, did you consider that the printer company will not provide drivers for Windows XP? I will have to print without modern proprietary drivers.

Comment: If the printer is networked as I suggested, XP might be able to add its driver (from the XP base of drivers), but that is out of support, so you would have to try to see.  I did when I had XP use a Print Server (printers did not commonly have Ethernet) and XP used the print server just fine.

Comment: This is a new printer, and in my experience, new printers' driver websites do not not support XP, Vista, even Windows 7 in most cases...

Comment: @cuddlybear - If there are not printer drivers for Windows XP then what you want is not possible.